# Swiss suffix -ikon in place names

Tags: geolinguistics

I've been wondering about the Swiss (exclusively, I think) suffix in place names like Opfikon, Oerlikon or my favourite Pfäffikon.

What is the origin of the `-ikon` or `-likon` ending? It seems particularly with Zürich area but maybe I'm not familiar enough with the rest of German-speaking Switzerland

Comment: Do you think Swiss-German -ikon is related to the Swiss-Italian place name suffix -nico such as in Anzonico, Chironico, Giornico?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's from German *Hof*, through the [suffix *-ighof*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hof_(Ortsname)) in German-speaking Switzerland.

From [LikeMag.com](https://likemag.com/de/das-bedeutet-die-endung-ikon-am-ende-vieler-schweizer-ortsnamen/529686):

> Zwischen dem 9. und 11. Jahrhundert, als die Alemannen sesshafter wurden, hängten sie oft die Endung -hofen an und schlossen damit alle ein, die zu einem Hof oder einer Grundherrschaft gehörten. Aus "Ditingen" konnte so "Ditighofen" werden. In der Mundart wurden die Endungen dann zu "-iken", "-ken", "-gen" oder eben "-ikon" verschluckt.

So it is related to the settling of the Alemanni between the 9th and the 11th centuries, when the addition of the suffix *-ighof* represented all those belonging to a court or a manor.